# AlertDialog with a ListView: two dividers between list item and button

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, divider

I show a list of items in AlertDialog by using AlertDialog.Builder's setAdapter() method. The problem is, the list draws dividers at the bottom of items and the buttons in the dialog are also separated frorm the listview by a divider. Thus, I get two dividers between the last item in the list and buttons. Anyone has any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
    android:fadingEdge="none"
```

of your list view

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
class C extends AlertDialog.Builder {

   private AlertDialog dialog;

   public SitePicker(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // sets data.....

    this.dialog = create();
    this.dialog.getListView().setDivider(null);
   }
}
```